# Java ExecutorCompletionService Issues

Tags: java

I was looking at source code here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.java
and it looks like in this method

```
protected void done() { completionQueue.add(task); }
```

they do not do super.done() like the following

```
protected void done() 
{ 
     super.done();
     completionQueue.add(task); 
}
```

does it mean that if I have say a class that extends FutureTask and that overrides the done() method, that body of code will never be executed if I use ExecutorCompletionService?

I am referring to this block of code

```
private class QueueingFuture extends FutureTask<Void> {
116        QueueingFuture(RunnableFuture<V> task) {
117            super(task, null);
118            this.task = task;
119        }
120        protected void done() { completionQueue.add(task); }
121        private final Future<V> task;
122    }
```

Comment: If you follow the code, `QueuingFuture`s are created from `Callable`s and `Runnable`s so there is no `done` method to call...

Comment: I am actually referring to thisprivate class More ...QueueingFuture extends FutureTask<Void> {
116        More ...QueueingFuture(RunnableFuture<V> task) {
117            super(task, null);
118            this.task = task;
119        }
120        protected void More ...done() { completionQueue.add(task); }
121        private final Future<V> task;
122    }
123

Comment: I know - and that class is only used internally to wrap a Callable or a Runnable. You can pass a FutureTask to the executor but since the method signature expects a Runnable, you can't expect the FutureTask methods to be called, other than run...